# Can't get ref when component is imported using next/dynamic

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, next.js13, ag-grid-react

I have aggrid table component - which I'm importing using next/dynamic - `ssr: false`

When I'm importing like this

```
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
```

The ref is working

[image: working ref]

but when I import it like this - it is not working

```
const AgGridReact = dynamic(() => import('ag-grid-react').then((module) => 
 module.AgGridReact), {
  ssr: false
});
```

[image: Ref not working]

Component

```
 const gridRef = useRef(null); 

  <AgGridReact
    ref={gridRef}
    rowData={rows}
    columnDefs={columns}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    animateRows={true}
    pagination={true}
    paginationPageSize={25}
  />
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it is because the lazy-loaded components with disabled ssr, load the component after hydration. maybe it will be solved by lazy-loading the whole component or use the ref value when you are sure that the component is hydrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your AgGridReact component as a separate component and then import it using dynamic keyword. Here's how

Install dependencies

```
npm install --save @ag-grid-community/core @ag-grid-community/react @ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model @ag-grid-community/styles
```

Add a new component to wrap your AgGridReact component. In this one, I have used modules instead of packages. It's benefical if you want to decrease your bundle size. You can still import the whole library if you want.

wrappedAgGrid.tsx

```
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react'
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css'

import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core'
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model'

ModuleRegistry.registerModules([
    ClientSideRowModelModule,
])

export default function WrappedAgGrid({ forwardedRef, ...props }) {
    return <AgGridReact {...props} ref={forwardedRef} />
}
```

Now import that WrappedAgGrid component and pass your ref

index.tsx

```
import { forwardRef, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"

const students = [
    {
        first_name: 'Bob',
        last_name: 'Harrison',
        gender: 'Male',
        address:
            '1197 Thunder Wagon Common, Cataract, RI, 02987-1016, US, (401) 747-0763',
        mood: 'Happy',
        country: { name: 'Ireland', code: 'IE' },
    },
    {
        first_name: 'Mary',
        last_name: 'Wilson',
        gender: 'Female',
        age: 11,
        address: '3685 Rocky Glade, Showtucket, NU, X1E-9I0, CA, (867) 371-4215',
        mood: 'Sad',
        country: { name: 'Ireland', code: 'IE' },
    },
    {
        first_name: 'Zahid',
        last_name: 'Khan',
        gender: 'Male',
        age: 12,
        address:
            '3235 High Forest, Glen Campbell, MS, 39035-6845, US, (601) 638-8186',
        mood: 'Happy',
        country: { name: 'Ireland', code: 'IE' },
    },
    {
        first_name: 'Jerry',
        last_name: 'Mane',
        gender: 'Male',
        age: 12,
        address:
            '2234 Sleepy Pony Mall , Drain, DC, 20078-4243, US, (202) 948-3634',
        mood: 'Happy',
        country: { name: 'Ireland', code: 'IE' },
    },
]

const Component = dynamic(import('./wrappedAgGrid'))
const ForwardedRefComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <Component {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />
))

export default function Page() {
    const agGridRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('agGridRef', agGridRef.current)
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{width: 500, height: 500}}>
                <ForwardedRefComponent
                    ref={agGridRef}
                    rowData={students}
                    columnDefs={[
                        {
                            field: 'first_name',
                            headerName: 'First Name',
                            width: 120,
                        },
                        { field: 'last_name', headerName: 'Last Name', width: 120 },
                        {
                            field: 'gender',
                            width: 100,
                        },
                    ]}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: It works like a charm! - Thank you so much